# Can't set array of features in vectorSource openlayers

Tags: vue.js, openlayers

I'm having an issue where I try to set my VectorSource with my features array from my state but I get "feature.getId is not a function".

What I would like is the have my feature displayed depending on my state, because i'll have filter and I need to fave feature on map reacting with filters.

How can i set my features list in the feature in my VectorSource ?

I'm getting my state array like this :

```
getAllFeature() {
      return this.$store.getters.GET_ALLFEATURES;
    },
```

then i'm trying to passe the array in the vectorSource

```
source: new VectorSource({
              format: new GeoJSON(),
              features: this.getAllFeatures,
            }),
```

Notice that I modified the form of my array comparing to the native geojson file I have

```
    getGeoJSONData() {
      axios
        .all([
          axios.get("http://localhost:8080/germany.geojson"),
          axios.get("http://localhost:8080/france.geojson"),
        ])
        .then(
          axios.spread((...responses) => {
            const features = [];
            responses.forEach((res) => {
              features.push(res.data.features.flat());
            });
            this.$store.dispatch("LOAD_FEATURES", features.flat());
          })
        );
    },
  },
```

Even if I try to set the strict same array that I receive from one of the Geojson, i have this error.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: GeoJSON features are not the same as OpenLayers features, you will need to call `new GeoJSON().readFeatures()` on each GeoJSON object (or push all the GeoJSON features into a single GeoJSON object and then call `readFeatures` once.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer ! Ok I'm really new to all of this, so what you mean is when I try to set my features inside my vectorSource, i'll need to call new GeoJSON().readFeatures() on ALL object inside my array so openlayers can ready them ? 
Because my object inside my array looks like this : object { propertires (object), geometry (object)}. I tried to make with the first object of my array,    features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(this.getAllFeatures[0]), no more error but there's nothing displayed on the map

Comment: EDIT : OK i found one of the issue, in my axios call, i didnt imported all the features geojson but only the feature, therefore I had no Type : FeatureCollection but it still says Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'feature_code')